# Angularjs - How can I replace special char from $http json result?

Tags: angularjs

How do I replace the following charachters ***"&#39"*** returned from ***$http data***
with ***" ' "*** ?

this is my code:

```
  $scope.searchInput = "";

  $scope.getResults = function(){
    $http.get('http://myapi'+ $scope.searchInput).
    success(function(data){

        $scope.myResults = data;

    });
  };

  $scope.getResults();
```

This is what the Json Object title looks like:

```
title: "&#39;Mad Max&#39; Review: 5 Reasons Why &#39;Road Warrior&#39; Is Better Than ..."
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your question properly , u need to escape the $scope-data object using $sce (Strict Contextual Escaping) dependency $sce.trustAsHtml can be used for this , please refer this
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

```
     $scope.doDecode = function(title){
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(title);
     };
```

//html

```
       <h2 ng-bind-html="doDecode(title)"></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to unencode `"&#39;"` you could use:

```
 $scope.searchInput = "";

  $scope.getResults = function(){
    $http.get('http://myapi'+ $scope.searchInput).
    success(function(data){
        data.title.replace(/&#39;/g, "'");
        $scope.myResults = data;

    });
  };

  $scope.getResults();
```

Comment: when I try this i get the error: "Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined"

Comment: You suggested the return data looked like `{title: "&#39;Mad...", title: "Jurasic World"}` but if it was e.g. `{movies: [{title: "&#39;Mad..."}, {title: "Jurasic World"}]}` you would need to do adjust accordingly to e.g. `data.movies[0].title.replace(/&#39/g, "'")` - or iterate over each.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to add this in my Html file: `ng-bind-html="object.title"`

```
   <div class="card" ng-repeat="object in Results" >
    <div class="item item-divider">
      {{object.visibleUrl}}
    </div>
    <div class="item item-text-wrap" ng-bind-html="object.title">
     {{object.title}}
    </div>
  </div>
```